# Expand/collapse multiple table rows with a more elegant solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I have multiple tables with data.

Fiddle:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/72TFR/)

---

The `<th>` is in a `<tr>` with a class name and each of the rows have similar naming...

`rowToClick1` `rowToClick2`

...and so forth.

---

Inside a for loop, where I generate data dynamically - I have `<tr>`'s with class names and similar to above they are named...

`rowToExpand1` `rowToExpand2`

...and so forth.

---

Currently, my solution is working for expanding/collapsing these tables, but it is really **ugly**:

```
$('.rowToClick1').click(function () {
    $(this).find('span').text(function (_, value) {
        return value == '-' ? '+' : '-';
    });
    $(".rowToExpand1").toggle();
});

$('.rowToClick2').click(function () {
    $(this).find('span').text(function (_, value) {
        return value == '-' ? '+' : '-';
    });
    $(".rowToExpand2").toggle();
});

// Many more similar functions repeatedly, up to 20+ ..
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

**Note:** I don't want the tables to expand/collapse at the same time, but individually (like I do now).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sure, simplified Fiddle provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// binding the event to the 'th':
$('th').click(function () {
    // finding the contained 'span' element, manipulating its text (as before):
    $(this).find('span').text(function (_, value) {
            return value == '-' ? '+' : '-';
        // finding the closest 'thead' (in which the 'th' elements are contained:
        }).closest('thead')
        // finding the sibling 'tbody' element:
        .next('tbody')
        // finding the 'tr' descendants:
        .find('tr')
        // toggling their visibility:
        .toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/72TFR/4/).

The above works if you have only *one* `<tbody>` element; if you should have multiple elements [that approach doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/72TFR/5/) (due to the use of `next()`); should there be (potentially) more `<tbody>` elements then you could instead use `nextAll()`:

```
$('th').click(function () {
    $(this).find('span').text(function (_, value) {
            return value == '-' ? '+' : '-';
        }).closest('thead').nextAll('tbody').find('tr').toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/72TFR/6/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I don't need class names anymore, since they were only delegated to make my script work. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! :)

Comment: Ok, this works fine! But how can I expand rows in the top and the bottom? Example: I have a table with 50 rows. When the page is loaded, the table shows rows 20-25. The rows 1-19 and 26-50 should be rolled out by cklicking links above/under row 20 and 25... You know, what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr[class^="rowToClick"]').click(function () {
    $(this).find('span').text(function (_, value) {
        return value == '-' ? '+' : '-';
    });
    var className = $(this).attr("class");
    var id = className.replace("rowToClick","");
    $(".rowToExpand"+id).toggle();
});
```

Comment: can you post sample html at jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: simplified Fiddle provided, see question again

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this...

http://jsfiddle.net/72TFR/2/

```
$('tr[class^="rowToClick"]').click(function () {
    // remove all non-numbers from the class with regex
    theNumber = $(this).attr('class').replace(/\D/g,'');
    // append the variable to the class name
    $(".rowToExpand"+theNumber).toggle();
});
```

Take a look at the documentation:

`tr[class^="rowToClick"]` : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Thank you @superUntitled for the answer, but I don't need class names anymore since they were only delegated for the purpose of making my script work.