# Bootstrap Collapsing Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make several rows collapse when I click on the parent row. currently, i am only able to collapse a single row, but i need to be able to close +2 rows at the same time.

Below is my current code, in this code I cannot figure out how to collapse both the "HIDDEN" and "HIDDEN 2" rows when I click on the first row.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
.hiddenRow {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>


<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <table class="table">
    <tr id="main" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <td>
        test
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="hiddenRow">
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse in" aria-labelledby="headingOne">HIDDEN</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="hiddenRow">
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse in" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">HIDDEN 2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: where's your JS?

Comment: what do you mean? this is just an html page, no scripts aside from jquery and bootstrap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `id="main" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"` use this example.  https://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/DTcHh/33622/

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order1">
  <td>+</td>
  <td>1001</td>
  <td>9/29/2016</td>
  <td>$126.27</td>
</tr>
<tr class="collapse order1">
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Shirt</td>
  <td>$12.27</td>
</tr>
<tr class="collapse order1">
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Shoes</td>
  <td>$62.27</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you can change the html to `<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order1">
      <td>
        test
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse order1">
      <td>HIDDEN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse order1">
      <td>HIDDEN 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`

Comment: The JS fiddle works exactly how i need mine to work, however, when i move it into an HTML file it is only showing the first hidden element, and I'm very unsure as to why it is unable find the second hidden element

Comment: The same happens when I use the html you added in your comment

Comment: do you have `<tr class="collapse order1">` in the second tr tag as well?

Comment: yes, i copied the code exactly from the JS fiddle, to check if it worked in my HTML file

`<tr class="collapse order1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Shirt</td>
      <td>$12.27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse order1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Shoes</td>
      <td>$62.27</td>
    </tr>`

Comment: I figured out what the error was, it was an error with the placement of my jquery script (it was below the bootstrap script)

Comment: Glad I can help

Answer (score 2):

Because it seems that bootstrap is using the `href` to call the collapse function, it isn't possible to collapse more than row at a time. This is because the href can only hold one link, which in this case is the id for the row that is successfully collapsing. I tried a few hacks, such as using an inline `onclick="location.href = '#collapseOne #collapseTwo'"` to give the href two links on the fly, but this didn't work. Also tried to switch from using the href as the collapser to `data-target`, which should work with `data-toggle` to define multiple targets, but also unsuccessfully. This looks like it's an open issue for bootstrap:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19813

This means that the best way is to either use some CSS magic i.e. `#main:active {.collapse {display:none}}` (only works with a preprocessor like `less` or `sass`) or to write some jquery to easily achieve the effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").on("click", function(){
        $("#collapseOne, #collapseTwo").hide();
    });
});
```

This implementation only hides the targeted id's, something like `.toggle()` instead of `.hide()` would be bidirectional.

Another method would be to nest a table inside of the row that is successfully collapsing, which should collapse the entire table inside of the row. But this is just a spitball and I haven't tested.

Here are some duplicates seeking to solve the same problem!

[Expand/collapse multiple table rows with a more elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890912/expand-collapse-multiple-table-rows-with-a-more-elegant-solution)

[expand/collapse table rows with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926752/expand-collapse-table-rows-with-jquery)